# hang-up in my Code

Tags: php, mysql

as title : php hang-up with my code

can please tell me why Or What is the problem

here is my code

```
<?php

$group = $_GET['group'] ;

$email = $_GET['email'] ;

include("../includes/config.php")  ;

if($group != '')
    {

       $query = mysql_query(" SELECT email FROM users WHERE `group`='$group' ") ;


       $emails = '' ;

           while($res = mysql_num_rows($query))
               {
                 $emails .= $res[0] ;
               }

    }

$emails .= $email ;

echo $emails ; die();

?>
```

Before While loop

i tried to check my query and its ok

after loop

There is no answer from the server

i'm using php 5.2.6

Comment: You should enable error reporting to the highest level when you develop. It should have given you a warning when accessing `$res[0]` for the first time as that is an undefined index. Learn about it, you will use it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.errorfunc.php

Comment: Careful now... You'd better use `addslashes()` before you use `$group` in your database. If someone enters the URI `yoursite.com/yourpage.php?group=';UPDATE users SET admin='true' WHERE email='hacker@hacker.com'--`, he may have admin access to your site. (This is an example, of course. I don't know your SQL architecture, but the point is: it's not safe to forget `addslashes()`).

Comment: From the PHP manual on addslashes(): "It's highly recommended to use DBMS specific escape function (e.g. mysqli_real_escape_string() for MySQL or pg_escape_string() for PostgreSQL)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid SQL injections you should replace

```
$group = $_GET['group'] ;
```

for

```
$group = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['group']) ;
```

Then, you have to execute the query and then iterate over the resultset, not what you are doing which is iterate over the amount of rows in the result (which is constant for each resultset and always evaluates to true, creating an infinite loop)

```
$res = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    $email .= $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i know about sqlinjetion  and usually use addslashes, but now my variable is  numeric   ,  and before while loop i tested my query and it work fine " test result in phpmyadmin"

Comment: Read my comment on the other answer, you are using the wrong function in the loop!

Comment: sorry : was using mysql_num_rows  and i should use mysql_fetch_row  thank you @Vinko Vrsalovic

Answer (score 2):

Try using `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_num_rows` in your loop.

Answer (score 2):

You typically would want to use [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) instead of the [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) since the latter one returns number of rows and not the result.

Comment: Yes thats true , but i always use mysql_fetch_row and work fine

Comment: @PasserBy But you are using mysql_num_rows instead of mysql_fetch_row